# vb.net implicit conversion to date

Tags: oracle, vb.net

I have an oracle table that stores string values as follows:

23/11/28 06:00:00

Next i am using vb.net in order to get that value into web application

```
    sql = "select TO_CHAR(Shift) AS Shift from events.dietracking_app_chart_data"
            adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
            Adapter.Fill(ds, sql)


                For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                    Dim strShift As String
                   

                    strShift = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)("Shift")
                Next j
```

But i can't get it in the format 23/11/28 06:00:00, instead, it turns to format '28-dec-23'. How to keep original format?

I was using FORMAT function, changed explicitly data types in query but i did manage to succeed

Comment: set the date format https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/6381/index.html

Comment: Incidentally, you could use a DataTable instead of a DataSet, then you could use, say, `dt` instead of `ds.Tables(0)`.

Comment: Just get the value of the `Shift` column as is. You will then get `DateTime` values in your app and you can just format them at the point of display. You've given no indication how you're displaying them, so we can't really say what the best way to do that would be.

Comment: I would like to display data as 23/11/28 06:00:00 on column chart as an XAxis label

Comment: Why are you worried about the format coming out of the database? So long as the datetime is coming out correctly, parse it into a date on the client and handle the formatting there. Types should be returned as their appropriate types rather than casting everything around as a string. The DB is there to return, group, and aggregate data for you. Display formatting is for the client/application to handle.

Answer (score 4):

Never rely on implicit string formatting. If you are going to use `TO_CHAR` to return a formatted string then explicitly specify the format model:

```sql
select TO_CHAR(Shift, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS Shift
from   events.dietracking_app_chart_data
```

Otherwise, read the value as a `DATE` and convert to whatever format you need in VB:

```sql
select Shift
from   events.dietracking_app_chart_data
```

Comment: I am not overly familiar with Oracle database types, however I suspect that you mean to say "read the value as a `DateTime`" instead of `DATE` and SO has too many pending edits for me to change it for you.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless No, Oracle does not have a `DateTime` data-type; it has `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` and they both have date and time components (`TIMESTAMP` can also have fractional seconds and a time zone) so when I said read the value as a `DATE`, I did mean read it as an (Oracle) `DATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something here, but DATETIME objects are stored as such in any database and VB.SQL knows this, so get your value as a `DateTime` object and display it any way you like in your code using `ToString(format)`.

Based on your comment that you could not get the right format:

```
Console.Write(Now.ToString("yy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss"))
```

Produces `23/12/14 02:16:17`

Comment: I made small changes in the sql query where i explicitly converted Shift to 'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI' 

"TO_DATE(SHIFT,'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI') AS SHIFT"

and now after declaring viariable 
Dim Shift as DateTime 

and assigning value to that variable as follows:

Shift = ds.Tables(0).Rows(j)("Shift")

i am getting following format of date #11/28/2023 12:00:00 AM#

So, it's one step closer but still i can't get date to be in format 23/11/28 06:00:00.
I couldn't create format in the ToString function to get it as i need

Comment: Maybe the question should be how to format the date inside code instead of how to get the SQL returned in a particular way, I see no advantage in getting a custom string date returned from a database that is unusable 'as-is'.